# REQUEST_URI Leading Forward Slash Missing

Tags: php, apache, curl

The following code snippet is used to log incoming requests:

```
//
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

error_log('HTTP' . $host.$path);
```

Among others, the following record appeard in the log (assuming the server public IP address is `2.0.0.1`)

```
[19-Jul-2020 10:55:19 UTC] HTTP 2.0.0.12.0.0.1:80
```

How can this request be reproduced? I'm unable to reproduce it without having `/` in the `REQUEST_URI`

```
[19-Jul-2020 10:55:19 UTC] HTTP 2.0.0.1/2.0.0.1:80
                                       ^
```

Command used:

```
curl example.com/2.0.0.1:80 -H "Host:2.0.0.1"
```

Comment: The actual HTTP “command” for a GET request is something like `GET /foobar HTTP/1.1`, the domain part is specified via the `Host` request header. So that someone manages to send a request of the form `GET HTTP/1.1` using _some_ client/interface/script, is possible. (Whether that would actually be a _valid_ HTTP GET request, would be a different matter.)

Comment: Does that mean it cannot be reproduced using curl? @CBroe

Comment: Don’t know, you’d have to check what options are available, and if maybe some combination of them is able to reproduce this result. I’ve never had a need to reproduce a “bogus” request like this, so I can’t say if cURL will automatically inject a `/` if the actual request path isn’t specified using any of the available options.